# Question for finding a determinant of a set of matrixes with given determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $A$ and $B$ are $3×3$ matrices, and $\det{A} = -2$ and $\det B = 3$, which of the following is equal to $\det (3A^T B^2 AB^{-1})$?

I got: $3 \times (-2) \times 9 \times (-2) \times \frac13 = 36$

But apparently that is wrong for some reason. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix, then $$det(kA)=k^nA^n.$$

Comment: Note that multiplying a matrix by $k$ is the same as multiplying it by $kI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. So you need to consider the determinant of this matrix.

Comment: Thx @QiaochuYuan, the theorem for that was in the previous section, so I must've missed it.